# Extract Element information from Input tag in a Webpage

Tags: html, vba, input

I have an Excel Macro successfully writing to a website using `.getElementByID("TBPRODDESC#####").value` where ##### is a unique ID for the input box, however there are certain instances when the `<input>` is disabled / stock value is zero or below the number being entered.  Whilst the macro continues without error it would be useful to identify when this occurs.

The `<input>` has the tag "InStock" within the input box however as there are multiple instances of this tag within many different input ID's, I am unsure how to extract this information for a specific Input ID

Below is an example of two of the `<input>` that i am working with

(1)
`<INPUT disabled id=TBPRODDESC11111 value=0 name=TBPRODDESC11111 InStock="0">"`

- looking to identify that TBPRODDESC11111 is disabled or TBPRODDESC11111 / "InStock" = 0

(2)
`<INPUT id=TBPRODDESC33333 value=0 name=TBPRODDESC33333 InStock="5">`

- looking to identify that TBPRODDESC33333 / "InStock" = 5

On the page there are approximately 100 Input elements each with a unique Input ID.

I can write to the input using
IE.Document.getElementById("TBPRODDESC11111").Value = Cells(3, "C").Value

but using 
Stkflag = IE.Document.getElementByTagID("InStock").Value always give 0 as I am unsure how to specify which ID InStock tag I need

Any help understanding how to achieve this check would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var inStock1 = document.getElementByID("TBPRODDESC11111")[0].getAttribute("InStock")
var isDisabled1 = document.getElementByID("TBPRODDESC11111")[0].hasAttribute("disabled")
```

and

```
var inStock3 = document.getElementByID("TBPRODDESC33333")[0].getAttribute("InStock")
```

I'm however slightly confused with this mix of JavaScript and Excel..

Comment: It's not a mix, VBA has a library to interact with HTML DOM and this library offers functions proper to JS that hence have the same name and similar syntax. But the user is coding in VBA, not JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you could use querySelector.

```
let elInputs = document.querySelector('[id^="TBPRODDESC"]');
```

And then you can do your business logic on that array of elements.
For example you can filter all disabled elements like this:

```
let elDisabled = [];
for(let i=0; i<elInputs.length; i++) { 
  if(elInputs[0].disabled == true)
    elDisabled.push(elInputs[0]);
}
```

For InStock property:

```
let elValidInStock= [];
for(let i=0; i<elInputs.length; i++) { 
  if(elInputs[0].hasAttribute("InStock") && elInputs[0].getAttribute("InStock") > 0 )
    elValidInStock.push(elInputs[0]);
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for quick reply but filtering is not really what I need to do as the macro loops through all the items stocked by the supplier that we purchase and fills in the website with the stock to be ordered.   If I can identify how to extract the "InStock" Tag value from the INPUT then I can use that to flag that the item will not be ordered or lower stock than needed will be ordered.

Comment: maybe you can use .getAttribute("InStock") method on the input element

Answer (score 0):

If you don't share the webpage I can't really test this, but I guess you want to:

- Get all the`<input>` elements of the page
- Get the `id` value of all those inputs having `InStock` > 0
- Do something with this `id` (set a value I guess?)

Try this code:

```
Set mInputs = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("input") 'get all inputs
For Each mInput In mInputs 'loop through each of them
    If mInput.hasAttribute("InStock") Then 
        If mInput.getAttribute("InStock") <> "0" Then
            'this sets directly the value
            mInput.Value = "something"
            'you can get the id like this if you need it somewhere else:
             mId = mInput.getAttribute("id")
        End If
    End If
Next mInput
```